# Create an Edit view similar to Contacts App

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have an edit view in my app which is a instance of UITableViewController and contains one cell with a textfield in a grouped table.

At the moment this cell is at the top of the screen and is firstResponder so they keyboard is visible as well. But in all the Apples apps like the Contacts App when you edit a piece of information like an Email it buts both of its rows in the middle between the Nav Bar and the Keyboard not at the top of the screen.

How do I achieve this effect?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IB, on the Size Inspector for the table view, set the Content Inset to say 50 or in code do this:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```